# Html2Canvas then Canvas2Image cutting the generated image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm trying to generate a PDF from a Html calendar on my web app, but when I convert the html into a cavas and than convert it to and image I got the image cutted, missing the last part of the calendar.

[image]

The cropping of the image depends on the screen size, if I try to generate it on a bigger screen it looks like this:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
var html2Obj = html2canvas($('#calendar'));
var queue = html2Obj.parse();
var canvas = html2Obj.render(queue);
var img = canvas.toDataURL();
window.open(img);
var doc = new jsPDF('landscape', 'cm');
doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 1, 1, 27.7, 19);
doc.save('calendar.pdf');
```

So, how can I create that screenshot without losing the page content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think jspdf uses some default page height based on screen size but there is no practical height limit in pdf spec. you can just increase page size so that it can include more stuff.Pass a `[width,height]` in the constructor you may need to adjust exact value by trail and error

```
var doc = new jsPDF('landscape', 'cm', [50,50]);
doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 1, 1); //no explicit dimensions
doc.save('calendar.pdf');
```

EDIT:
If that is the case then pass desired height width value in constructor

```
var html2Obj = html2canvas($('#calendar'),{width: desiredWidth,height:desiredHeight});
```

Comment: Actually the croping is being done on the conversion from html to canvas to image, the generated PDF is well sized.

Comment: What positioning does your canvas use?

Comment: It almost work now, but now, the calendar goes to the center of the generated canvas and it keeps cutting half of the calendar.

How could I set the canvas the size of the div I want to convert ?

Comment: "cutting half of the calendar" where? in canvas gen. image or pdf ? incase its canvas increase your `<canvas> or <div>` dimensions through css

Comment: It cuts the content of the canvas, if I try to append the generated canvas to the body, its not shown, if I open the generated image its cutted and in the PDF it's also just half the calendar.


I've tried this way:
var html2Obj = html2canvas($('#calendar'), { width: $('#calendar').width(), height: $('#calendar').height() });

Comment: Now I increased the size on the constructor for something like 5000 width and 5000 height, and then it worked.